# (SOLVED) Java Hibernate - QuerySyntaxException: Class is not mapped

Tags: java, hibernate

**SOLVED**
The error I made was in the `ConnectionUtils` class, basically I was configuring hibernate without adding classes.
For anyone habing this problem I will leave new `ConnectionUtils` class.

**PROGRAM INFO**
Hi, I'm new to Hibernate framework and I'm developing a simple program that manages an Hostel.
I've made and populated a mySQL database called 'hostel_db' and I want to build a java desktop application
that enables me to interact with the database.

**QUERY PROBLEM**
I have done some research on how to setup and connect to a database with Hibernate, now I am trying to make a simple query on it to show elements in a table, but I get "QuerySyntaxException: Class is not mapped" as output.
Apparently the connection is done successfully but for some reason I can't figure out where I'm failing.

This is what the program (part of it) looks like:
**PS**: the connection details (username, password, etc. are done with a ConnectionUtils class).

**mySQL DATABASE**

```
CREATE TABLE hostel (
    hid             VARCHAR(10)     PRIMARY KEY,
    rooms           INT             NOT NULL,
    profit          INT             DEFAULT 0,
    cost            INT             DEFAULT 0
);
```

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!--Use Hibernate's own connection pool configuration-->
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hostel_db</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>

        <!--hibernate dialect-->
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>

        <!--Print sql statement-->
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">false</property>
        <!--Format sql-->
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql">true</property>

        <!-- Load map file -->
        <mapping resource="com/hostelmanagment/tables/config/Employee.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="com/hostelmanagment/tables/config/Student.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="com/hostelmanagment/tables/config/Hostel.hbm.xml"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
             http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="com.hostelmanagment.tables">
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**Hostel**

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Entity
@Table (name = "hostel")
public class Hostel implements Serializable {
    // DATABASE ATTRIBUTES
    @Id
    @Column (name = "hid")
    private String hid;
    @Column (name = "rooms")
    private int rooms;
    @Column (name = "profit")
    private int profit;
    @Column (name = "cost")
    private int cost;

    // OTHER VARIABLES

    // CONSTRUCTOR
    public Hostel() {}

    public Hostel(String hid, int rooms, int profit, int cost) {
        this.hid = hid;
        this.rooms = rooms;
        this.profit = profit;
        this.cost = cost;
    }

    // GETTERS
    public int getRooms() {
        return rooms;
    }

    public int getProfit() {
        return profit;
    }

    public int getCost() {
        return cost;
    }

    //

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return hid + " - Rooms: " + rooms + " - Profit: " + profit + " - Cost: " + cost;
    }
}
```

**hostel.hbm.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <!-- name:full path to class:-->
    <!-- table: table name: (can be omitted. Use the class name as the table name.)-->
    <class name="com.hostelmanagment.tables.Hostel" table="hostel">
        <!--Primary key-->
        <id name="hid" column="hid">
            <!--Primary key generation strategy-->
            <generator class="native"></generator>
        </id>
        <property name="rooms" column="rooms" type="java.lang.Integer"/>
        <property name="profit" column="profit" type="java.lang.Integer"/>
        <property name="cost" column="cost" type="java.lang.Integer"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Main**

```
package com.hostelmanagment;

import com.hostelmanagment.gui.*;
import com.hostelmanagment.tables.Hostel;
import com.hostelmanagment.utils.*;
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.persistence.Query;

import org.hibernate.*;

import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Connect to database
        EntityManager em = ConnectionUtils.connectToDatabase(ConnectionData.getUsr(), ConnectionData.getPsw()).
                createEntityManager();
        Session session = ConnectionUtils.connectToDatabaseSession(ConnectionData.getUsr(), ConnectionData.getPsw()).
                openSession();

        // Test show data from databases

        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        Query query = session.createQuery("from Hostel");
        List<?> list = query.getResultList();
        Hostel hostel = (Hostel) list.get(0);
        System.out.println("\nHostel: \n" + hostel);

        // Run GUI
        //new HostelMainFrame(em);
    }
}
```

**ConnectionUtils**

```
public class ConnectionUtils {
    private static Map<String, String> databaseProperties = new HashMap<>();
    private static Configuration databaseConfiguration = new Configuration();
    private static final String dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect";
    private static final String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hostel_db";
    private static final String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";

    public static EntityManagerFactory connectToDatabase(String username, String password) {
        // Try to set up the configuration for hibernate.cfg
        try {
            databaseConfiguration.configure().
                    setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", username).
                    setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", password);
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            if (verifyHibernateConfigXml())
                throw new RuntimeException("Wrong format for hibernate.cfg.xml");
        }

        // Build configurations
        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder ssrb = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().
                applySettings(databaseConfiguration.getProperties());
        SessionFactory factory = databaseConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(ssrb.build());

        // Setup persistence
        persistenceSetup(username, password);

        // Return EntityManagerFactory
        return Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("com.hostelmanagment.tables", databaseProperties);
    }

    public static SessionFactory connectToDatabaseSession(String username, String password) {
        // Try to set up the configuration for hibernate.cfg
        try {
            databaseConfiguration.configure().
                    setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", username).
                    setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", password);
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            if (verifyHibernateConfigXml())
                throw new RuntimeException("Wrong format for hibernate.cfg.xml");
        }

        // Build configurations
        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder ssrb = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().
                applySettings(databaseConfiguration.getProperties());

        // Setup persistence
        persistenceSetup(username, password);

        return databaseConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(ssrb.build());
    }

    private static boolean verifyHibernateConfigXml() {
        try {
            InputStream is = ConnectionUtils.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("hibernate.cfg.xml");
            return true;
        } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
            throw new RuntimeException("hibernate.cfg.xml don't exists");
        }
    }

    private static void persistenceSetup(String username, String password) {
        databaseProperties.put("hibernate.connection.driver_class", driver);
        databaseProperties.put("hibernate.connection.url", url);
        databaseProperties.put("hibernate.connection.autocommit", "false");
        databaseProperties.put("hibernate.connection.username", username);
        databaseProperties.put("hibernate.connection.password", password);
        databaseProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", dialect);
        databaseProperties.put("hibernate.connection.CharSet", "utf8");
        databaseProperties.put("hibernate.connection.characterEncoding", "utf8");
        databaseProperties.put("hibernate.connection.useUnicode", "true");
        databaseProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        databaseProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
    }
}
```

**FOLDER STRUCTURE**
[image: folder structure]

**STACK TRACE**
[image: stack trace]

**NEW CONNECTION UTILS**

```
public class ConnectionUtils {
    private static Map<String, String> databaseProperties = new HashMap<>();
    private static Configuration databaseConfiguration = new Configuration();
    private static final String dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect";
    private static final String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/".concat(ConnectionData.getDbName());
    private static final String driver = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver";
    private static EntityManagerFactory emf;
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public ConnectionUtils(){}

    public void setUpProperties() {
        propertiesSetup(ConnectionData.getUsr(), ConnectionData.getPsw());

        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder standardServiceRegistryBuilder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().
                applySettings(databaseConfiguration.getProperties());
        //standardServiceRegistryBuilder.configure();

        emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(ConnectionData.getTablesPackage(), databaseProperties);
        sessionFactory = databaseConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(standardServiceRegistryBuilder.build());
    }

    public EntityManagerFactory getEntityManagerFactory() {
        return emf;
    }

    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    private static void propertiesSetup(String username, String password) {
        // Try to set up the configuration for hibernate.cfg
        try {
            databaseConfiguration.configure().
                    setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", username).
                    setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", password);
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            if (verifyHibernateConfigXml())
                throw new RuntimeException("Wrong format for hibernate.cfg.xml");
        }

        // Setup persistence
        persistenceSetup(username, password);
    }

    private static boolean verifyHibernateConfigXml() {
        try {
            InputStream is = ConnectionUtils.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("hibernate.cfg.xml");
            return true;
        } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
            throw new RuntimeException("hibernate.cfg.xml don't exists");
        }
    }

    private static void persistenceSetup(String username, String password) {

        try {
            for (Class cls : getEntityClassesFromPackage(ConnectionData.getTablesPackage())) {
                databaseConfiguration.addAnnotatedClass(cls);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }

        databaseProperties.put("hibernate.connection.driver_class", driver);
        databaseProperties.put("hibernate.connection.url", url);
        databaseProperties.put("hibernate.connection.autocommit", "false");
        databaseProperties.put("hibernate.connection.username", username);
        databaseProperties.put("hibernate.connection.password", password);
        databaseProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", dialect);
        databaseProperties.put("hibernate.connection.CharSet", "utf8");
        databaseProperties.put("hibernate.connection.characterEncoding", "utf8");
        databaseProperties.put("hibernate.connection.useUnicode", "true");
        databaseProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        databaseProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
    }

    private static List<Class<?>> getEntityClassesFromPackage(String packageName) throws ClassNotFoundException, URISyntaxException {
        List<String> classNames = getClassNamesFromPackage(packageName);
        List<Class<?>> classes = new ArrayList<Class<?>>();
        for (String className : classNames) {
            Class<?> cls = Class.forName(packageName + "." + className);
            Annotation[] annotations = cls.getAnnotations();

            for (Annotation annotation : annotations) {
                System.out.println(cls.getCanonicalName() + ": " + annotation.toString());
                if (annotation instanceof javax.persistence.Entity) {
                    classes.add(cls);
                }
            }
        }

        return classes;
    }

    private static ArrayList<String> getClassNamesFromPackage(String packageName) throws URISyntaxException {
        ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();

        packageName = packageName.replace(".", "/");
        URL packageURL = classLoader.getResource(packageName);

        URI uri = new URI(packageURL.toString());
        File folder = new File(uri.getPath());
        File[] files = folder.listFiles();
        for (File file: files) {
            String name = file.getName();
            name = name.substring(0, name.lastIndexOf('.'));  // remove ".class"
            names.add(name);
        }

        return names;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the complete stacktrace

Comment: @Jens added, thanks for remembering me and sorry that I was only able to upload a picture.

Comment: Normally, it is not that good to mix `hibernate.cfg.xml` with `persistence.xml` ... If you go for the path of JPA annotations, I´ll suggest to delete `hibernate.cfg.xml` and work only with the `persistence.xml` file ...

Comment: @CarlitosWay actually I'm configuring the connection with the 'Conifuguration' class from Hibernate so I need to use `hibernate.cfg.xml`. However I don't think the problem is related to them.

Comment: I have experienced the error that you're showing ... however, in my case it was because the domain classes (i.e. the classes annotated with `@Entity`) reside in another jar artifact that the one having the `persistence.xml` file... to fix the problem, I just added the fully qualified name of the classes (i.e. the class name including its package) into the `persistence.xml` file with the tag `<class></class>` (However, in such deployment, there was not `hibernate.cfg.xml` file!)

Example: `<class>com.hostelmanagment.tables.Employee</class>`

Comment: @CarlitosWay I actually tried adding classes to persistence.xml, did some reasearch on proper mapping, but nothing came out. But I tried adding an `Hostel` object to the database and it works correctly, but this uses `EntityManager`. So I think that there is something wrong in the way I initialize `Session` in the `ConnectionUtils` class i made. However thank you!

Comment: Good you solved your problem. It is advised to answer your own question then. SO then better shows what was solved and how.